# How to include those tuples that don't fulfill a specific criterion?

Tags: sql, sql-server

> `Items(ItemCatalogNo, ItemType, ManufacturerName, Model, Price, QtyInWarehouse)`
>
> `Supplies(SupplyNo, SupplierID, DateOrdered, DateReceived, ItemCatalogNo, Amount)`
>
> **For each item type and manufacturer, give the total number of items of that were supplied.**

```
SELECT  Items.ItemCatalogNo,
        Items.ItemType, 
        Items.ManufacturerName,
        sum(Supplies.Amount) as TotalSupply
FROM    Items, 
        Supplies    
WHERE   Items.ItemcatalogNo = Supplies.ItemcatalogNo
GROUP BY Items.ItemType, Items.ItemCatalogNo,Items.ManufacturerName
;
```

This query only gives the tuples of those `ItemTypes` which were supplied.

If I also need to incorporate those items that were not supplied (in which case, `TotalSupply` should show `0` or `null`), what to do?

Should I use `UNION`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`left outer join` retrieves a row even when the condition is not met, filling the secondary table (supplies) with nulls.

`coalesce(first, second)` replaces null values in first parameter with second parameter, so when amount is null, it sums 0. Actually you can have multiple parameters, coalesce takes the left-most value that is not-null.

```
SELECT  Items.ItemCatalogNo,
        Items.ItemType, 
        Items.ManufacturerName,
        sum(coalesce(Supplies.Amount,0)) as TotalSupply
FROM    Items 
left outer join Supplies on Items.ItemcatalogNo = Supplies.ItemcatalogNo
GROUP BY Items.ItemType, Items.ItemCatalogNo, Items.ManufacturerName
```

**Note:** When using more than one table in a query prefer using `left outer join` (or `join`) to link them through its primary and foreign key, and let the `where` clause for actual conditions that retrieved rows must comply. This way is easier to distinguish the domain relationships from the particular conditions in the query.

Comment: If I want 0 instead of null, what to do?

Comment: You use coalesce, check the sum() parameter I put instead of supplies.ammount

Answer (score 2):

Use a left join

```
SELECT  Items.ItemCatalogNo,
    Items.ItemType, 
    Items.ManufacturerName,
    sum(Supplies.Amount) as TotalSupply
FROM    Items 
Left outer join Supplies    
on   Items.ItemcatalogNo = Supplies.ItemcatalogNo
GROUP BY Items.ItemType, Items.ItemCatalogNo,Items.ManufacturerName;
```

If you want zero instead of null for non-existing items use coalesce.

```
SELECT  Items.ItemCatalogNo,
  Items.ItemType, 
  Items.ManufacturerName,
  coalesce(sum(Supplies.Amount),0) as TotalSupply
FROM    Items 
Left outer join Supplies    
on   Items.ItemcatalogNo = Supplies.ItemcatalogNo
GROUP BY Items.ItemType, Items.ItemCatalogNo,Items.ManufacturerName;
```